# Why Metal Frame Capture "GPU time" is completely different from other methods

Tags: ios, xcode, benchmarking, metal, metalkit

There are a lot of methods to see how much `GPU Time` it takes per one frame.

1. Xcode Debug Navigator > FPS > Frame Time > GPU
2. Metal Performance HUD > GPU
3. Measure manually with

```
commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { buffer in
    let gpuTime = buffer.gpuEndTime - buffer.gpuStartTime
}
```

All those 3 methods show identical numbers for me. But Metal Frame Capture also shows `GPU Time` and it's completely different.

I issue Metal Frame Capture programmatically for the scope of one frame, so it should measure the same workflow.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let captureDescriptor = MTLCaptureDescriptor()
    captureDescriptor.captureObject = device
    try! MTLCaptureManager.shared().startCapture(with: captureDescriptor)

    // frame code
    
    MTLCaptureManager.shared().stopCapture()
}
```

But when all other methods show `14.2ms`, Metal Frame Capture show `7.81ms` with Induced performance state, `5.48ms` with Maximum, `9.48ms` with Medium, and `18.06` with Minimum.

So with none of the performance states it even remotely resembles the number shown elsewhere.

Are we just not supposed to think about GPU time shown in Metal Frame Capture as the same thing, and only compare it with other GPU Times within the Metal Frame Capture itself?

I guess for comparing against the 16.6ms target should be used the first 3 methods. On the other hand GPU Frame Capture **should not be used** for comparing against specific GPU time target, but it is more suitable for relative fine-grained comparing of optimization impacts?

The thing is also that some of my code optimizations in shaders show dramatic improvements (like 2x) in Metal Frame Capture `GPU Time`, but only marginal (a couple of %) gains if looking only on `GPU Time` in Xcode or Performance HUD. I don't know which metric to use to decide if certain optimization worth it or not.